# Python countdown solver

Tags: python

I'm learning to code in python and am creating a countdown solver for practise, I have gathered the numbers the user inputs and generated the target number, I have then gathered all possible permutations for the inputted numbers and operators but I am struggling to find a way to find sets of numbers and operators that equal the target number.

code:

```
import random
import itertools
answerlist = []
operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
solutions = []
numberperms = []

def generatetarget():
    global targetnum
    targetnum = random.randint(100, 999)


def askquestion():
    global answerlist
    questionflag = 0
    while questionflag != 5:
        answerquestion = input('would you like a high or low number? ')
        if answerquestion == 'low':
            answer = random.randint(1, 10)
            while answer in answerlist:
                answer = random.randint(1, 10)
            print(answer)
            answerlist.append(answer)
        elif answerquestion == 'high':
            answer = random.randint(11, 20)
            while answer in answerlist:
                answer = random.randint(11, 20)
            print(answer)
            answerlist.append(answer)
        questionflag = questionflag + 1

def permutations():
    global opperms
    numperms = list(itertools.permutations(answerlist))
    opperms = list(itertools.permutations(operators))
    print(opperms)

def countdownsolver():
    global answerlist, targetnum, operators, solutions, numberperms, opperms
    numcount = len(numberperms)
    opcount = len(opperms)            

generatetarget()
askquestion()
permutations()
countdownsolver()
print(answerlist)
```

I tried using the eval() function, but is there a better way? I am unsure of what to do.

Comment: quick hint, as you are a beginner.  try to avoid globals, as (whilst they are allowable) they are considered poor practice in larger code bases...  in this case, you can easily use arguments in the functions to control the flow of the code better.

Answer (score 0):

to make your code better, first, move the line where you ask the user for input inside the loop. This lets them guess in every round.

Next, check the part where you compare if the number is greater or less than the guess. Make sure the indentation is right, and the 'Try higher' and 'Try lower' messages are inside those blocks.

Change the if statement to elif when you're checking if the number is equal to the guess. It just makes things smoother.

Lastly, check the indentation of the else block. Make sure it lines up with the outer loop for cleaner code

Comment: these are just general comments and whilst useful in general it is **not an answer** to the question. did you forget to add the code ?

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I am struggling to find a way to find sets of numbers and operators that equal the target number. ..."*

Here is an example.
It's not exact; you'll still need to incorporate a parenthesis operation.

I'm using the rules from the *Wikipedia* article, *"[Countdown (game show)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_(game_show)#Numbers_Round)"*.

```java
import random as r, itertools as i
Ns, Nl = [*range(1, 11)] + [*range(1, 11)], [25, 50, 75, 100]
r.shuffle(Ns), r.shuffle(Nl)
N = Nl[:int(input('how many large numbers?  '))]
N += Ns[:6 - len(N)]
T = r.randint(111, 1000)
R = []
for s in i.chain(*(i.permutations(N, r) for r in range(2, len(N) + 1))):
    for op in '+-*/': R.append(op.join(str(x) for x in s))
print(f'N = {N}')
print(f'T = {T}')
t = min(R, key=lambda x: abs(T - eval(x)))
print(f't = {t} = {eval(t)}')
```

Output

```
how many large numbers?  3
N = [50, 100, 25, 8, 9, 3]
T = 163
t = 50+100+9+3 = 162
```

```
how many large numbers?  0
N = [7, 10, 8, 10, 4, 9]
T = 631
t = 7*10*9 = 630
```

```
how many large numbers?  1
N = [25, 2, 6, 7, 10, 2]
T = 838
t = 2*6*7*10 = 840
```

```
how many large numbers?  2
N = [75, 50, 9, 10, 6, 2]
T = 293
t = 50*6 = 300
```

To note, if you want to review the results of *R*, you can use the following.

```py
[print(f'{eval(x)} = {x}') for x in sorted(R, key=lambda x: abs(T - eval(x)))]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this will be sure to improve my code.